# Form Helper form_open() not working in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: codeigniter-4, form-helpers

It doesn't work....

`<?=form_open('userupdate')?>`
`<?=form_close()?>`

Getting `404 error`.

I tried without short tag also.

The form tag works fine....

```
<form method="post" action="<?php base_url('userupdate')?>" name="frmUserUpdate">
</form>
```

While UserAdd form works fine using form_open() method. Please note that I have declared in `autoload.php` and in `BaseController.php`.

I spent lot of time but I couldn't figure out where is the problem?

Can anyone look into this?

Controllers:

`$routes->get('useredit/(:num)', 'UserControllers\UseraddController::useredit/$1');`

`$routes->post('useredit/(:num)', 'UserControllers\UseraddController::update/$1');`

Comment: I can't see i route definition for `userupdate`. Where is it? And what do you have declared in `autoload` and `BaseController`? `helper('form');`?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the helper is included with your methods or in BaseController

**UseraddController.php**

```php
    public function useredit()
    {
        helper('form');
        //...
    }


    public function update()
    {
        helper('form');
        //...
    }
```

**BaseController.php**

```php
    protected $helpers = [
        //...
        'form',
    ];
```